# MUI Slide Transition doesn't work with two Slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, slide

I want the animation for each mui Slide to work when the button is clicked. But for some reason they don't want to work together. If you comment out one of the slides, the second one starts working, but together they don't.

Here's a link on codesandbox with my sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-fire-csr2go?file=/src/demo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the `isPink` to control the rendering of the component, when the condition is not true, the component is unmounted when `update`, and no animation is performed.

```js
// don't use this
{isPink ? (<div></div>) : (<div></div>)}
```

#### Code Fragment

```js
        <Grid container item>
          <Slide
            in={isPink}
            direction="left"
            container={containerRef.current}
            mountOnEnter
            unmountOnExit
          >
            <Box
              sx={{
                position: "absolute",
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                bgcolor: "pink"
              }}
            >
              <Button onClick={() => setIsPink(false)}>show aquamarine</Button>
            </Box>
          </Slide>
          <Slide
            in={!isPink}
            direction="right"
            container={containerRef.current}
            mountOnEnter
            unmountOnExit
          >
            <Box
              sx={{
                position: "absolute",
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                bgcolor: "aquamarine"
              }}
            >
              <Button onClick={() => setIsPink(true)}>show pink</Button>
            </Box>
          </Slide>
        </Grid>
```

#### Full code demo

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]